# Wrapping code around highlighted content in a contenteditable DIV using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

I have a contenteditable div as a substitute for a textarea. I want to wrap   tags around text that is highlighted when a link is clicked.

The jQuery code is as follows:

```
 $('a#b').click(function(){
var highlight = "";

if (window.getSelection) 
{
    highlight = window.getSelection().toString();
} 

else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") 
{
    highlight = document.selection.createRange().text;
}   


var b = '<strong>' + highlight + '</strong>';
content = $('#sel').html();

range = highlight.getRangeAt(0);

startText = content.substring(0, range.startOffset);
endText = content.substring(range.endOffset, content.length);

$('#sel').html(startText + b + endText);
});
```

The problem is that the above code is not working. Any ideas what may be wrong ? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have a look at `execCommand()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Comment: **$('a#b').click(function()**. May be you should correct this. **$('#ab').click(function()**.

Comment: This is not the problem. "a#b" implies <a> tag with id attribute = "b"